# How do I isolate and amplify faint dialogue on an audio track?

Tags: audio, recording

I have a video that shouldn't have any sound in it and I can faintly hear someone talking. My question is how do I isolate and amplify these sounds to hear them without straining and reducing other background noise?

Comment: Suggest you edit the 'question' so that it is a question, and not really a statement.

Comment: You might want to look at using something like iZotope RX Dialogue Isolator, or Dialogue Denoiser. That is really the only way that you will be able to isolate and increase the dialogue level to a degree where it is intelligible.